# WPF Binding Error for ComboboxItem when using the ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a WPF application (.Net 4.5.1) where I create the items in a combo box dynamically, I bind to the ItemSource with an observable collection. But when I do this i get two binding errors, one for VeticalContentAlignment and one for HorizontalContentAlignment, for each item that I add.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : 
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. 
BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name='PhoneItem'); 
target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

I have googled and found some pointers that **did not help**, e.g. adding a global style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
 </Style>
```

or defining an inline container style in the combo box.

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
       <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I can reproduce this in a clean project where I have no styling and only a combo box bound to an observable collection if anyone is interested in having a look at my stripped code.

**Update 1 - My XAML and code behind**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationDynamicComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>

            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="5">Load Combobox</Button>

            <ComboBox Name="DynamicComboBox"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                      Width="400"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this;
    MyItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
    MyItems.Add( new ComboBoxItem {Content = string.Format( "Phone: {0}", "123" ), Name = "PhoneItem_" + DateTime.Now.Second} );
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> MyItems { get; set; }

  private void ButtonBase_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
  {
    MyItems.Add( new ComboBoxItem {Content = string.Format( "Phone: {0}", "123" ), Name = "PhoneItem_" + DateTime.Now.Second} );
  }
}
```

**Update 2 - Link to sample project**
http://bit.ly/1fwvgkZ

Any help getting rid of these errors are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you link me a clean project where I can reproduce it?

Comment: Can you post the XAML code where your ComboBox is defined?

Comment: I suspect the error is related to the way you have `Binding` defined for the `ComboBox`. Please post the xaml code and also your `ViewModel` or xaml code behind.

Comment: @FodderZone thanks for helping out, I have added my xaml and code behind in the original question. I hope you can spot any errors I have made!

Comment: @aks81 thanks for helping out, I have added my xaml and code behind in the original question. I hope you can spot any errors I have made

Comment: @lll I have added a link to a sample project in my second update, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay fixed your error. Just replace your code behind with

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
        MyItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem
        {
            Name = "PhoneItem_" + DateTime.Now.Second,
            Content = string.Format("Phone: {0}", "123"),
            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        });
    }


    public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> MyItems { get; set; }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem
        {
            Name = "PhoneItem_" + DateTime.Now.Second,
            Content = string.Format("Phone: {0}", "123"),
            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, this had me stumped for quite a while - don't know why I did not even think of setting the offending properties explicitly.

Comment: Sometimes even I loose common sense while coding. It's a part of being a developer :)